# Error error de inicio de sesión Paypal Android Studio

Tags: java, android, paypal, studio

hace algunas semanas estaba trabajando en los pagos de PayPal, todo iba perfectamente, pero luego de algunos días me comenzó a aparecer un error "error de inicio de sesión" y no se porque sucede este error. Este es el código.

Ante esto me gustaría que en realidad me pudieran ayudar, por que llevo días sin saber por que sucede esto y antes estaba todo normal.
Estoy utilizando Java en Android Studio y me comenzó a funcionar todo completamente funcional, pero al querer iniciar sesión me comenzó a aparecer eso error, estuve viendo videos de como arreglar, pero son de más de 7 años y no pude solucionarlo. Mostrare mi código del error y también mostrare el código de mi activity no estaré haciendo ninguna modificación para que vean todo como yo lo veo.

dependencia:    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'

el código del activity es:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import app.ejemplo.proyectoapp.Config.Config;

public class MainApoyanos extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE= 7171;

    private EditText et1;
    private ImageButton btnp;
    private Button btn;
    private String monto="";
    private String tien="PayInsurance";

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this,PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
            .acceptCreditCards(true);






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_apoyanos);


        Intent intent=new Intent(MainApoyanos.this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);


        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPaypal);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPaypal);
        btnp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBack12);

        btnp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainApoyanos.this,SegundoActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainApoyanos.this, getString(R.string.Bienvenidodevuelta), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });






        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                procesarPago();
            }
        });

    }

    private void procesarPago() {
        monto=et1.getText().toString();

        PayPalPayment payPalPayment=new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(monto)),"MXN","Para AppInsurance",PayPalPayment
        .PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent =new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if (requestCode==PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation= data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation !=null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails=confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this,activity_detallespago.class).putExtra("PaymentDetails",paymentDetails)
                        .putExtra("PaymentAmount",monto).putExtra("IdVendedor",Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID).putExtra("TiendaC",tien));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            }
            else if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.pagocancelado12), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (resultCode==PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.pagoinvalido), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

````
2021-02-26 13:58:20.038 27031-27235/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp E/paypal.sdk: Exception parsing server response
  org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
      at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.cs.m(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.fi.d(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.ce.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.onResponse(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.perf.network.zzh.onResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@@19.0.8:22)
      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2021-02-26 13:58:20.038 27031-27235/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:
2021-02-26 13:58:20.649 27031-27031/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
2021-02-26 13:58:20.650 27031-27031/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-02-26 13:58:20.656 27031-27031/app.ejemplo.proyectoapp E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ```
````

Answer (score 0):

El error

Exception parsing server response   org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

indica que no puede procesar la respuesta, esperaba un JSON pero en realidad recibe otro tipo de información.

Revisa que obtienes como valor de `confirmation` en `onActivityResult()` ( agrégalo a tu pregunta) , el problema es este valor que no viene como una respuesta json :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if (requestCode==PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation= data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation !=null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails=confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this,activity_detallespago.class).putExtra("PaymentDetails",paymentDetails)
                        .putExtra("PaymentAmount",monto).putExtra("IdVendedor",Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID).putExtra("TiendaC",tien));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```